# What is best way of calling a sound array in different places?

Tags: arrays, cocoa, audio

**My code:**

```
//Get the filename of the sound file:
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: [finalArray objectAtIndex:s]  ofType:@"wav"];
//declare a system sound id
SystemSoundID soundID;

//Get a URL for the sound file
NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];

//Use audio sevices to create the sound
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)filePath, &soundID);

//Use audio services to play the sound
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

As you see I use an array `finalArray` that is holding the values from a text file. I want to play a sound in three places of the code in `loadView` + `nextButton` + `PreButton`.

Do I have to load the same code in the three places? Or can I make this into a method that I can just call three times?

Answer (score 0):

no need to answer i think the best way is just calling it with a method like the following:

```
-(void) sound:(NSUInteger)s_obj;
```

so thank you I just tried it by myself and it works fine with one line

```
[self sound:s];
```